# how to take the data type pymc3.model.TransformedRV of pymc3 as the input of scipy.special function

Tags: python, scipy, pymc3

I am trying to use pymc3 to estimate the parameters of generalized inverse gaussian distribution (GIG), which involes the bessel function (coming from scipy.special). The inputs to the bessel function are supposed to be arrays, whereas alpha, beta, gamma are pymc3 classes. How do I get scipy.special functions to take pymc3 RV's as input? Running the code attached below produces an error

```
import pymc3 as pm
from scipy.special import hankel
import numpy as np


def gig(x, a, b, p):
    # c = p, is the order
    kp = special.hankel1e(p, x)
    y1 = ((a / b) ** (p / 2)) / (2 * kp * np.sqrt(a * b))
    y2 = (x ** (p - 1)) * np.exp(-(a * x + b / x) / 2)
    y = y1 * y2
    return y

with pm.Model() as gig_model:
    alpha = pm.Gamma('alpha', alpha=0.5, beta=2)
    beta = pm.Gamma('beta', alpha=0.5, beta=2)
    gamma = pm.Gamma('gamma', alpha=0.5, beta=2)
    
    def giglogp(x):
        lp = np.log(GIG(x, alpha, beta, gamma))
        return lp
        
    # likelihood
    Like = pm.DensityDist('likelihood', giglogp, observed=dt)
```

```
TypeError: ufunc 'hankel1e' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Comment: Check the docs, but it's safe to assume that `scipy.special` functions expect float dtype arrays, or something that can safely be converted to that.  If the error message is confusing, try to do your own conversion before hand, e.g. `np.asarray(your_variable, dtype=float)`.

Comment: thanks for your response. One question is that the dtype of variable is TransformedRV, it can not converse np.asarray()